# Variable is empty with jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to run a code only if the date of my task is not empty. But currently, the code is running with a empty date. Can you explain me where is my error ?

```
var date = '<%=@task.date%>'
if( date != null){
  $('.sn_date').html('<i class="fa fa-calendar-o" id="fa_icons"></i><%=@task.date.strftime("%d %b")%>')
}
```

Comment: `''.empty?` is true, `'' != null` is true, what do you mean with empty, do you have any hint in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

First case:

```
<script>
var date = <%=@task.date.present?%>
if( date){
  $('.sn_date').html('<i class="fa fa-calendar-o" id="fa_icons"></i><%=@task.date.strftime("%d %b")%>')
}
</script>
```

if `@task.date` is nil or empty, `.present?` will return false, else true. In any conditions your `var date` will be boolean.

Second case:

```
<script>
var date = <%=@task.date%>
if( !!date){
  $('.sn_date').html('<i class="fa fa-calendar-o" id="fa_icons"></i><%=@task.date.strftime("%d %b")%>')
}
</script>
```

in this case your `var date` will be string, does not matter what will return `@task.date`, nil or string date. And now in js you should verify if `var date` not empty string `if (!!date) {}`.

`if date = ''` => `!!date` return `false`

`if date = 'date'` => `!!date` return `true`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but weirdly is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried validating with Ruby then dumping out your JS if the date is present?

```
<% if (@task.date.present?) %>
 $('.sn_date').html('<i class="fa fa-calendar-o" id="fa_icons"></i><%=@task.date.strftime("%d %b")%>')
<% end %>
```

Comment: At the end I'll do that, I don't know why, I cannot solve that with jQuery condition

Comment: Check your @task.date what is default value when it is empty or not setted.  Maybe this variable every time it's not empty

Comment: Well if there is no date, the value is null. So I don't understand why your solution is not working

Comment: Just make this inside your js tag `console.log("<%=@task.date%>")` and shoe here console output

Answer (score 0):

you can validate with **" "** empty, something like that `if (date != ""){
your sentence.... }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NEFEGAGO, but I your solution is not working for me